# XMPP server-to-server routing inside a domain

Tags: routes, xmpp, instant-messaging, server-to-server

I'm learning about Instant Messaging system and read about XMPP(RFC6120,6121,6122). These documents refer to client-to-server and server-to-server communication(using domain name), but they don't say about server-to-server routing in a domain. Can you show me some solutions or documents refer to this problem?

ex: user A want to send messages to user B, user A connect to server1, user B connect to another server in the same domain with server1(ex:example.com), so how server1 know which server(IP address) has connection with user B to forward messages?

Answer (score 2):

Routing inside a domain is not an XMPP features but is a server dependant feature. This is what clustering layer of a given XMPP server do.

For example, in ejabberd, there is basically a session table (that can be store in various back-ends) that reference user resource and the node on which that session and TCP/IP connection lives.

XMPP specification does not define how to build a cluster as this is a technical implementation detail.

Comment: Do you know any algorithm or protocol to solve this problem? Ex: how does ejabberd build and maintain session table in a cluster?

Comment: ejabberd uses Mnesia database replication to replicate session table on the cluster.